# Unable to SSH into CentOS HVM instance on AWS: No supported authentication methods available

Tags: centos, putty, login, ssh-keys

I have a similar question to [this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1142012/unable-to-ssh-into-server-no-supported-authentication-methods-available/1142072#1142072?newreg=b5e754fab9e14f66b9d5405f49e5cda4), but the info provided doesn’t help me.

I set up a CentOS HVM instance on AWS to learn Linux. My initial (root?) account `centos` can log in fine using the initial key pair I created on AWS console. Using PuTTY (after PuTTYgen to generate teh appropriate kley foromat locally), on login I was presented with the key challenge and I elected "yes" to save it locally.

I don't know where the (separate) login challenge key is stored locally on my Windows laptop when I initially logged into the server using that account. It must be stored by username or Windows username. I only know where the PuTTYgen-converted PPK file is.

I created a second user on the Linux box `ec2usr`. I set is password using sudo passwd. I want to test this new account by logging in with it from PuTTY, but I get that same message - even though I directed PuTTY to the same PPK key file I'm using with my `centos` account login that works.

I have only created one key pair on AWS console.

I've tried loading the AWS console key pair fingerprint from that key pair into PuTTY, it still doesn't work.

When I attempt to login I never get a chance to save the challenge key - it should prompt me to do this and it doesn't. Why not?

Nothing out of the ordinary here - this is as basic as it gets. What am I missing?

If I'm using PAgeant I don't know it, I doubt that I am.

Answer (score 0):

Putty uses its own format, the CentOS uses OpenSSH key format.

Either way, you have to *authorize* the key you have for the `ec2usr`.

Having the same password as `centos` does not have anything to do with it.

You are using *key* based authentication only (password one is disabled in AWS by default).

To authorize a key, you have to put its *public* counterpart to `<USER HOME DIR>/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

If you've just created a user, it may not even have the `.ssh` directory.

The following creates it (provided that you're logged in under that user):

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 0700 ~/.ssh
touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

If you don't have at hand the *public* key (for adding to `authorized_keys` file), you can just copy it from `/home/centos/.ssh/authorized_keys`. It must be there, because your login to `centos` user works.

Comment: thanks! I created the account using a different password - but I haven't used it, as you point out its key-based.  I can't log in using that account, so how do I perform the above?  I would have to do it as _'centos'_.  But you state I have to be logged in as that user. I thought _centos_ as my initial account/user would have root privs, but I can't even cd into _/home/ec2usr._  .I thought I would be prompted to save a (private?) key upon first login as a unique user, but obviously that didn't happen.  In my prior experience with unix, this is all that was required...not sure why.

Comment: I performed these commands as _centos_ using sudo, but I still can't login as _ec2usr_. I copied my authorized_keys file from my .ssh folder to ec2usr's .ssh folder.  But on attempted login I get "server refused our key".

Comment: Those commands are to be run by user you want to login with. Run `sudo -iu ec2usr` to “become” that user while logged in to `centos`

Comment: Perhaps I should have edited the (what appeared as empty) authorized_keys file, instead of overwriting it with the one from the centos .ssh folder?

Comment: just saw your response.  so how do I undo what I've done and start over?

Comment: Either way you have to ensure it’s owned by the user you want to login with. And not run those commands with sudo. Because running with sudo means it’s run by root

Comment: ahh, ok, I just figured that out <grin>.  since _ec2usr_ isnt in the sudo group, I had to do some of the commands (ie: rm the .ssh folder, re-copy the auth_keys file over etc) as _centos_ using sudo.

Comment: so I"m a bit surprised these steps are necessary....would you have any idea why I didn't have to do this before (that was probably an RHEL linux)?  Will I have to do this every time I create a new user?

Comment: This is kind of basic SSH... you do it because password authentication is off: create `authorized_keys` and put the public keys you want to be able to access a given account.